# tsc: Unable to calibrate against PIT

Tags: boot, 16.04, dmesg

```
$ dmesg | grep tsc
[    0.000000] tsc: Unable to calibrate against PIT
[    0.000000] tsc: using HPET reference calibration
[    0.000000] tsc: Detected 4008.361 MHz processor
[    1.608138] tsc: Refined TSC clocksource calibration: 4008.029 MHz
[    1.608140] clocksource: tsc: mask: 0xffffffffffffffff max_cycles: 0x39c5fcfe866, max_idle_ns: 440795249027 ns
[    2.608431] clocksource: Switched to clocksource tsc
```

1. What is a tsc?
2. What does `Unable to calibrate against PIT` mean?

Comment: See [Time Stamp Counter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_Stamp_Counter) and [High Precision Event Timer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_Precision_Event_Timer). I don't know what the specific message means - possibly just the kernel checking  various legacy timer support options.

Comment: @steeldriver Thanks for the direction. I have to do more research on this.